# When to clear listeners from innner RecyclerView when it is being used inside another RecyclerView(outer)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView`(Horizontal Layout) inside another `RecyclerView`(Vertical Layout). Everything works fine. Now I want to add `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` listener to the inner `RecyclerView`.

I am adding a listener to the inner RecyclerView on `onViewAttachedToWindow` of the adapter callback and clearing it on `onViewDetachedFromWindow`. It works fine. But If I go back from the fragment, I am not getting any callback for `onViewDetachedFromWindow` and thus the listeners **remain added** to the inner `RecyclerView`s.

Now my questions are:

- Will fragment's `onDestroyView` result in clearing out all the listeners from **those inner** `RecyclerView`s?
- Since I am creating the instance of the listener inside the outer `RecyclerView`'s `ViewHolder`, so will it get automatically destroyed when its Fragment is destroyed?

If none of the above will happen, how should I clear those listeners because that may result in the memory leak as the listeners hold `RecyclerView`'s reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom `RecyclerView` (inner) and override it's `onScrollStateChanged` method and have implemented scroll-changed the logic there.

I also had to set some custom dataset to the listener, which I am setting while setting the adapter for the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1):

> - Will fragment's onDestroyView result in clearing out all the listeners
>   from those inner RecyclerViews?
> - Since I am creating the instance of the listener inside the outer RecyclerView's ViewHolder, so will it get automatically destroyed when its Fragment is destroyed?

I don't think it will, instead this can potentially cause a memory leak.

The reason why `onViewDetachedFromWindow` is not called is because the `ViewHolder` is not removed from it's parent.

I think it's better to move the ownership of the listener to the owner of the view (`Activity`/`Fragment`) instead of the outer `RecyclerView`. But if you still want to keep the ownership like your current implementation you can try to call `setRecycleChildrenOnDetach(true)` in your `LinearLayoutManager` to make the `LinearLayoutManager` remove all views when `RecyclerView` is detached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Niko. But there is one problem with the solution as mentioned in the doc **Note that, setting this flag will result in a performance drop if RecyclerView is restored.**  I have found another work-around for it. Anyway, upvoting your answer. :)

Comment: @RohitArya Yes, actually this way is only recommended if you use your own RecyclerView Pool, glad that you found your solution! :)

Comment: @RohitArya and I think you should check your own answer as the correct answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take benefit of `onDestroyView` and send callBack to your outer `RecyclerView` parent component only, so that will be only responsible to set listener of inner `RecyclerView` which can be either null.